# The last 2 digits of $7^{7^{7^7}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the calculation way to find out the last $2$ digits of $7^{7^{7^7}}$? WolframAlpha shows  $...43$.

Comment: Because you are working with the last 2 digits of $7^n$, note that it is periodic with pattern $01, 07, 49, 43, 01, \ldots$.

Comment: In the number theory chapter this exercise has $2$ stars. It's considered hard.

Comment: @julien not really

Comment: $7\equiv -1 \pmod 4$ and $7^2\equiv -1 \pmod {25}$ make this exercise very easy....2 stars are probably 2 too many :)

Comment: Euler's theorem predicts that the powers of $7$ will exhibit some periodicity modulo $100$. But the specific smallest period $4$ here is much smaller than the period $\phi(100)=\phi(2^2)\phi(5^2)=(4-2)(25-5)=80$ given by Euler's theorem, which works for all numbers coprime to $100$. So it turns out to not be very helpful.

Comment: @drjimbob Yes, look what I wrote: $(4-2)(25-5)=80$... My problem seems to be with $2\cdot 20=40$. A hard one.

Comment: Related: [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$7^2=49=50-1$

$\implies 7^4=(50-1)^2=50^2-2\cdot50\cdot1+1\equiv1\pmod {100}$

Alternatively, $100=4\cdot25, 7^2\equiv1\pmod 4$

and $7^2\equiv-1\pmod{25}\implies 7^4\equiv(-1)^2\pmod{25}\equiv1$

$\implies 7^{\text{lcm}(2,4)}\equiv1\pmod {4\cdot25}$ as $(25,4)=1\implies 7^4\equiv1\pmod {100}$

So, we need to determine $7^{7^7}\pmod 4$

As $7^7$ is odd, and $7\equiv-1\pmod4\implies 7^{7^7}\equiv-1\pmod4\equiv3$

$\implies 7^{7^7}=4n+3$ for some integer $n>0$

So, $7^{7^{7^7}}=7^{4n+3}\equiv (7^4)^n\cdot7^3\pmod{100}\equiv1^n\cdot343$

Comment: I am having trouble to understand the portion as highlighted in red:
$7\equiv-1\pmod4\implies 7^{7^7}\equiv-1\pmod4\equiv \color{red}{3}\,\,$ .

Can you please explain how $3$ came into the picture ?

Comment: @learner, As $7^{7^7}>0,$ the remainder will $\in [0,1,2,3]$. Now we have reached $-1\pmod 4\implies $ teh reminder is of the form $4a-1$ where $a$ is some integer. In we can set any $m$ such that $m\equiv-1\pmod 4$   please have a look into this : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: thank you so much sir.It is crystal clear now..

Answer (score 24):

Let's check the pattern of the last two digits of powers of $7$.
$$
7^1\to07\\
7^2\to49\\
7^3\to43\\
7^4\to01\\
7^5\to07
$$
and it loops. Thus we need only find out what that exponent is modulo $4$. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$7^{2k+1} \equiv3\pmod {4}$$
$$ 7^{7^{7^7}}\equiv3\pmod {4}$$
and $7^{3} \equiv43\pmod {100}$ &  the cycle has period $4$, then $7^{7^{7^7}}\equiv43\pmod {100}_\blacksquare$

Comment: How do you get to the final conclusion? Maybe in the second line you meant $7^{7^7}$ instead of $7^{7^{7^7}}$? (You need to derive that the exponent is $\equiv 3 \mod 4$, that $7^3 \equiv 43$, and together with $7^4 \equiv 1$ that then implies the result.)