# Last two and three digits of $7^{754}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

How can we find the last two and three digits of $7^{754}$?

I tried with the binomial expansion and all but i don't seem to reach anywhere with it. 
Is there any other way too?

Comment: Do the calculations mod 100 and mod 1000. For example, $7^3\equiv 43 \mod 100,$ so $7^{754} = 7^{3*251+1} = 7*(7^3)^{251} \equiv 7*(43)^{251} \mod 100.$ In this way, you can quickly reduce the exponent while the basis stays bounded.

Comment: @Aryaman, Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390685/the-last-2-digits-of-7777

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you mentioned the Binomial Theorem, let us use it. Note that we are finding the last three digits of $49^{377}$, that is, of 
$$(-1+50)^{377}.$$
Expand. We get 
$$(-1)^{377} +(377)(-1)^{376}(50) +\frac{(377)(376)}{2}(-1)^{375}(50)^2+\text{terms divisible by $1000$}.$$
Actually, $\frac{(377)(376)}{2}(-1)^{375}(50)^2$ is also divisible by $1000$, so we can forget about it.

Finally calculate the remainder when $(377)(50)-1$  is divided by $1000$. This can be done in one's head.

**Remark::** The calculation took advantage of the fact that $7^2$, from a decimal point of view, is "nice." The standard *general* procedure is to use a combination of the binary method of modular exponentiation, combined with number-theoretic results such as Fermat's Theorem and Euler's Theorem.

Answer (score 6):

The last two digits of powers of $7$ go in a cycle -$ 07, 49, 43, 01.$ So if raised to power $754$ it has remainder $2$ when divided by $4$ so last two digits are 49. Similarly go for three digits

Answer (score 4):

For the last digit, you need to find the remainder of $7^{754}$ when divided by $10$.

Take a look at the remainders of $7^n$ for small values of $n$:

- $7^1 \to 7$
- $7^2 \to 9$
- $7^3 \to 3$
- $7^4 \to 1$
- $7^5 \to 7$
- $7^6 \to 9$

Can you see a pattern?

You can do the same for two digits, the pattern is still there.

Comment: why isn't this considered as an optimal solution?

Comment: Using this to find the last 3 digits would extremely be tedious!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that binomial expansion is the way to go. Perhaps for 2 digits try mod 4 and mod 25 separately. For the 3 digits one try mod 8 and mod 125 separately.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to go about it?

Comment: I mean i only know how to do the mod 10 or mod 100.

Comment: See https://brilliant.org/wiki/chinese-remainder-theorem/