# If last two digits of $ 7^{7^{7}}=k$, find $k-38$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have managed to get the answer as $07$ using modular arithmetic but answer seems wrong to me because the answer after evaluation of $k-38$ is $5$.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show us your modular arithmetic?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390685/the-last-2-digits-of-7777

Comment: I had written the expression as 7^49

Comment: Sorry I have actually calculated wrong the last 3 digit I have found is 343 therefore last two digits 43 7^2 congruent to 49 mod 100 implies 7^48 congruent to 49 mod 100 thus I multiplied 7 on both side and got 7^49 congruent to 343 mod 100 or 43 mod 100 therefore 43-38 =5.  Solved my own silly doubt lol

Comment: I found $5$  mentally.  No big deal  because I knew that $7^4=2401\equiv 1 \mod {100}.$

Comment: Are you familiar with Euker's totient function? It makes Q's like this easy and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate that $7^7=823543$.

For the last two digits of $7^n$, we have this repeated cycle for $n=1;n=2;n=3;n=4;...$: $07\rightarrow49 \rightarrow43 \rightarrow01\rightarrow07 \rightarrow49 \rightarrow43 \rightarrow01 \rightarrow07 \rightarrow49 \rightarrow43 \rightarrow01 \rightarrow...$

We can conclude that if $k$ is a non-negative integer:

- $n\equiv1\pmod {4}$ then $7^n$ have two last digits $07$.
- $n\equiv2\pmod {4}$ then $7^n$ have two last digits $49$.
- $n\equiv3\pmod {4}$ then $7^n$ have two last digits $43$.
- $n\equiv0\pmod {4}$ then $7^n$ have two last digits $01$.

$43\equiv3\pmod {4}$, so $823543\equiv3\pmod {4}$.

We can conclude thet the last two digits of the expression is $43$, hence $k-38=43-38=5.$

Also, based on the comment on your problem, we all know that $7^{7^{7}}\ne7^{49}$, but $(7^7)^7=7^{49}$.

Comment: Please give me an answer in terms of mod.

Comment: I have edited as suggested.